# Postgres cascade delete with trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have following database structure:

```
table a (
    id     bigint primary key,
    del    timestamp
);
table b (
    id     bigint primary key,
    a_id   bigint references a(id) on delete cascade,
    del    timestamp
);
```

When deleting a record from table `a`, I want to set the `del` flag at the current time and cascase the corresponding flag in table `b` ( but not delete records from database actually).

For it, I write a trigger:

```
create or replace function a_delete_trigger()
    returns trigger as
$$
begin
    update a
    set del = now()
    where id = old.id; -- mark row

    return null; -- return null, so that the record is not removed from database
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
create trigger a_delete
    before delete
    on a
    for each row
execute procedure a_delete_trigger();
```

And a trigger for table `b`:

```
create or replace function b_delete_trigger()
    returns trigger as
$$
begin
    update b
    set del = now()
    where id = old.id;

    return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
create trigger b_delete
    before delete
    on b
    for each row
execute procedure b_delete_trigger();
```

When I delete a record from table `a` ( `delete from a where id = ?` ) , the record is marked as deleted ( the flag `del` contains timestamp), but appropriate records from table `b` are not marked (I'm guessing, that cascade delete not work, because I return null from trigger `a_delete_trigger`)

How do I make, that when I delete a record from table `a`, the record marks as deleted, and corresponding records in `b` will marked as deleted too?

Answer (score 0):

Add the delete b to the a_delete_trigger.

```
create or replace function a_delete_trigger()
    returns trigger as
$$
begin
    update a
    set del = now()
    where id = old.id; -- mark row

    delete from b where a_id = a.id;

    return null; -- return null, so that the record is not removed from database
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
create trigger a_delete
    before delete
    on a
    for each row
execute procedure a_delete_trigger();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want to use cascade deletions, I don't want list all dependencies of table `a`

Comment: The number of times I've known people trying to make RDBMS better, you wouldn't believe it. Why don't you keep a separate log of database actions?

Comment: We have log all needed database actions, but we need restore some historical information ( with relations and etc)

Comment: You could query PostgreSQL for the tables depending on table a, but it's a journey without end.